# routing broadcast UDP in/out of Docker for Mac container

Tags: docker

I want to run an application (the [OLA](https://www.openlighting.org/ola/) server, `olad`) inside a container under Docker for Mac. (Version 18.06.1-ce-mac73 on Mojave, all up-to-date.) The particular OLA configuration I am using (for the Art-Net protocol) works by sending and receiving UDP broadcast data over port 6454 on a particular physical ethernet interface on the host, which is in turn connected to an external device under control. Normally, when starting the `olad` server, one specifies the interface or IP address on which it should send/receive the broadcast messages.

My struggle is getting the UDP messages to and from the interface from inside the container. I don't appear to have access to that physical interface or network inside the Docker for Mac container, even if I run with `--network host`. My understanding is that this is because of a quirk of the way Docker for Mac is implemented, with an extra VM between my container and the hardware. That VM sees the hardware, but I don't.

Simply running the docker instance with `-p 6454:6454/udp` doesn't work, either, maybe unsurprisingly. I could see where that might allow incoming traffic to the container to find its way to the server, but the server inside still can't find the outside network/device in the other direction. And I'm not sure how OSX would necessarily get that data from the interface to the docker bridge anyway.

How can I get direct, bidirectional access to that interface or network from inside the container? Or if I cannot, is there some kind of workaround, maybe via `socat` where I could tunnel that network in through a Unix socket that is shareable between host and container?